# How to retrieve friends from a database ASP, C#, Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

With our current querys we only get the friend to show up on one of the friendlists in our web application. For example User A sends a friend request to User B. The problem is that User B who accepts the friend req is the only one who sees that they are friends in his friendlist. For UserA the User B does not show up in his friendlist.

Linq query to get friends into the friendlist:

```
public List<UserInformation> GetFriends(Guid UserID)
{
    var context = new dbDatingEntities();
    var Result =
                 from x in context.UserInformation
                 join y in context.Friends on x.UserId equals y.FromUser
                 join z in context.UserInformation on y.ToUser equals z.UserId
                 where z.UserId == UserID && y.Status == 1
                 select x;
    return Result.ToList();
}
```

Linq query for sending friend request:

```
public void SendFriendReq(Guid xFromUser, Guid xToUser)
{
    using (var context = new dbDatingEntities())
    {
        Friends objFriend = new Friends
        {
            FromUser = xFromUser,
            ToUser = xToUser,
            Status = 0
        };
        context.Friends.Add(objFriend);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Linq query for accepting friend request:

```
public void AcceptFriendReq(int reqID)
{
    using (var context = new dbDatingEntities())
    {
        var req = context.Friends.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == reqID);
        req.Status = 1;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: how did your friends get into the database in the first place???

Comment: @WeylandYutani, I was waiting for this comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You only select the relation as `From User ->  To User`, but you should also select them the other way around. If the `From` user is friends with the `To` user,  then the `To` user should also be friends with the `From` user:

```
where z.UserId == UserID && y.Status == 1
```

should be something like:

```
where (z.UserId == UserID || x.UserID == UserID) && y.Status == 1
```

or you should add the `Friends` twice, once for each order or `From` and `To`. This would allow users to be friends "one way": I could friend you but you might not want to friend me back. Depends on what you want to archieve, really.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line here is limiting the list to only friends where the user is in the `FromUser` field.

```
join y in context.Friends on x.UserId equals y.FromUser
```

Don't you need to also look in `ToUser` ?

This will only show the Friendships where this user has sent the request, and not where the current user received and accepted a request.

Comment: Yes, that is where our problem is. This code works when you add duplicate entries to the db with touser/fromuser switched around (this would happen at the moment a request is sent or accepted). But we wanted to see if there is a way to avoid that, and get the friend with just that one row. We have tried several things but can't figure it out.